# How do I enable grpc on port 443 in nginx without breaking http on port 80 in kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, grpc, kubernetes-ingress, tensorflow-serving, nginx-ingress

I am using Nginx on Kubernetes 1.19 (trying both docker desktop and GKE) and am trying to expose gRPC services. I have installed Nginx with the following command and confirm I can expose REST services on port 80 and gRPC services with proper configuration on port 443.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.41.2/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

However, after creating the gRPC ingress I can no longer reach standard REST services on port 80. I am met with a 502 as nginx tries to push this HTTP/1 traffic to my gRPC service. If I do `kubectl get ingress`, I can see the ingress is available on ports 80 and 443, whereas I only want 443. Here is the ingress (sorry for all the annotations - trying things out).

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    allowed-values: CN=client
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: default/localhost
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/grpc-backend: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 64ms
  name: tfserving-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: tfserving-service
          servicePort: 8500
  tls:
  - secretName: localhost
    hosts:
      - localhost
```

How do I create ingress for this domain with TLS that doesn't also redirect http traffic to my gRPC services?

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding multipke ingress on the same host, one with tls and another without tls.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    allowed-values: CN=client
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: default/localhost
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/grpc-backend: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 64ms
  name: tfserving-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: gRPC-service
          servicePort: 8500
  tls:
  - secretName: localhost
    hosts:
      - localhost

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    allowed-values: CN=client
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 64ms
  name: rest-http-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-rest-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes this works if I provide a path other than `/`, and I can reach the http ingress on 80 as well. However, if I don't provide a path it doesn't work:
```Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "other-ingress.yaml": admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request: host "localhost" and path "/" is already defined in ingress default/tfserving-ingress```